# Converting between Vec<i8> and &str

Tags: string, vector, type-conversion, rust, slice

I have a `Vec<i8>` I need to read as `&str`. Right now I've found two ways to do it, both of which leave me unhappy.

```
// Quite complex for something this simple
str::from_utf8(buffer.into_iter().map(|c| c as u8).collect::<Vec<u8>>().as_slice())
```

and

```
// transmute makes me uncomfortable
str::from_utf8(mem::transmute::<Vec<i8>, Vec<u8>>(buffer).as_slice());
```

Are there any simpler ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find that transforming to a `String` is nicer, given that you can pass `&String`s to functions expecting `str`s. You can shorten it to roughly

```
String::from_utf8(buffer.iter().map(|&c| c as u8).collect())
```

and the later can be shortened to just

```
String::from_utf8(mem::transmute(buffer))
```

I doubt you can do better than these.